# Difference in behavior between if_else and case_when with group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't figure out why these two are not behaving in the same way. The `case_when` one works as I expect it to, while `if_else` one gives the error:

```
Error: `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 2 
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The example code:

```
tb <-
  tibble(DC = c(1, 1, 2), ID = c(1, 1, 2), V = c(100, 200, 400)) %>% 
  group_by(DC, ID)

tb %>%
  mutate(V = if_else(sum(V) == 300, V / n(), 1))

tb %>% 
  mutate(V = case_when(sum(V) == 300 ~ V / n(), TRUE ~ 1))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `true` and `false` values in `if_else` should be of same length as `condition`. Here, `condition` is of length 1 (`sum(V) == 300`) whereas `true` value for 1st group is of length 2 (`V / n()`) hence, the error.

Since this is a scalar comparison you can use `if`/`else` instead.

```
library(dplyr)

tb %>% mutate(V = if(sum(V) == 300) V / n() else 1)

#    DC    ID     V
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1    50
#2     1     1   100
#3     2     2     1
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, but my question was why these two functions do not behave in the same way.

Comment: @PeteK Because these two are different functions and don't always behave the same.